# ASP.Net Core React Template Build Fails

Tags: node.js, reactjs, asp.net-core

I am trying to use the ASP.Net Core React Template on my Mac. After creating the project and running dotnet run I get the following errors:

```
EXEC : gyp ERR! stack error : `gyp` failed with exit code: 1 [/Users/natelandon/Documents/Projects/MedicalWeightLoss/MWLCA/MWLCA.csproj] EXEC : node-pre-gyp ERR! stack error : Failed to execute '/usr/local/Cellar/node/13.8.0/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build
--module=/Users/natelandon/Documents/Projects/MedicalWeightLoss/MWLCA/ClientApp/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v79-darwin-x64/fse.node
--module_name=fse --module_path=/Users/natelandon/Documents/Projects/MedicalWeightLoss/MWLCA/ClientApp/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v79-darwin-x64
--napi_version=5 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v79' (1) [/Users/natelandon/Documents/Projects/MedicalWeightLoss/MWLCA/MWLCA.csproj] EXEC : gyp ERR! stack error : `gyp` failed with exit code: 1 [/Users/natelandon/Documents/Projects/MedicalWeightLoss/MWLCA/MWLCA.csproj] EXEC : node-pre-gyp ERR! stack error : Failed to execute '/usr/local/Cellar/node/13.8.0/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build
--module=/Users/natelandon/Documents/Projects/MedicalWeightLoss/MWLCA/ClientApp/node_modules/jest-haste-map/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v79-darwin-x64/fse.node
--module_name=fse --module_path=/Users/natelandon/Documents/Projects/MedicalWeightLoss/MWLCA/ClientApp/node_modules/jest-haste-map/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v79-darwin-x64
--napi_version=5 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v79' (1) [/Users/natelandon/Documents/Projects/MedicalWeightLoss/MWLCA/MWLCA.csproj] /Users/natelandon/Documents/Projects/MedicalWeightLoss/MWLCA/MWLCA.csproj(30,5): error MSB3073: The command "npm install" exited with code -1.
```

The build failed. Fix the build errors and run again. I'm not sure how to fix these errors. If I run it again I get the following:

```
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices[0]
  npm ERR! errno 1
   npm ERR!fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices[0]
  npm ERR! mwlca@0.1.0 start: `rimraf ./build && react-scripts start`
   fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices[0]
  npm ERR! Exit status 1
   fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices[0]
  npm ERR! 
    ERR!fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices[0]
  npm ERR! Failed at the mwlca@0.1.0 start script.
   fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices[0]
  npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
   fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices[0]
  npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
   fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices[0]
  npm ERR!     /Users/natelandon/.npm/_logs/2020-02-12T23_45_37_941Z-debug.log
```

Any help on fixing this would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you navigate to ClientApp and run the build command to see the full error

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, ensure that Xcode is installed on the machine and up to date. Seems something that npm is doing (for the react components) requires Xcode.